# Adding a letter to an existing field without erasing the existing data

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

So, I think I have arrived at a solution for a database index problem, I have been having. It is throwing out claims that have duplicate "TIC" numbers. Of course these duplicates I have are 10 years apart. My solution is to go to the import file, and add a letter to the "TIC" field, e. g. "C" for Canada Claims, "B" for Brazil Claims etc. I need it to populate the correct letter in the "TIC" field, based on the data in the "Country" field. Here is the code I am trying to use now, but it is not working:

```
Sub AppendToTIC()

Dim d As Range
For Each d In Selection
  If d.Value = "Canada" Then e.Value = "C" & e.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Something is off in my logic, I think, but I am not sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is that the actual code?  You're making a reference to `e.value`, but you haven't defined `e` anywhere.

Comment: How does your data looks ? I believe it can be achieved using `LEFT` function.

Comment: I see what you are saying about defining e; what do you feel might work best. My data is a Country for column d and a number for column e. I am trying to set up the macros in an import file, then pull the trigger from Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking to append just the letter to the beginning of the next columns cell then this would work.

Issues you have
You do not define the range of D
you use D to loop through a selection but you necer select anything.

```
Sub AppendToTIC()

Dim d As Range
Set d = Selection
For Each c In d
    c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(c.Value, 1) & c.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next

End Sub
```